# Implode on associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like

```
$value = array('key1'=>'value1','key2'=>'value2','key3'=>'value3');
```

I want to convert this array to the following string.

```
key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3
```

I have tried with implode function, but it returns only values of the array

```
implode($value,"&"); // returns value1&value2&value3
```

Is there any simple way to achieve this ?

Comment: That's not a multidimensional array. It's just a one dimensional associative array. Anyway, you should checkout [http_query_builder()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). That will do what you want.

Comment: use `http_build_query($arr);`

Comment: Hi Magnus & Sudhir thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implode is used only on array values. It doesnot work on array keys. If you want to use it for building the query string then you can use `http_build_query` function in php.

```
$value = array('key1'=>'value1','key2'=>'value2','key3'=>'value3');

echo http_build_query($value); // key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3
```

Hope this helps.